# How to reject CC'ed email when emailing a mailbox for Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

Ill try to explain the scenario as best I can.  Basically, we have an Office 365 environment with AD Synced to our onprem AD servers.  We have a shared mailbox that will be used by a group of people.  However, they are wanting to prevent anyone from CCing someone that is already in the mailbox so that that person CC'ed doesnt both get an email in there own mailbox and the shared mailbox.

Example:

"john.doe@work.com" emails the "conversion@work.com" mailbox which has Ann Smith and Bob Smith added to the mailbox.  Ann is John Doe's manager and John wants to CC Ann Smith to the composed email going to "conversion@work.com".  Now the same email will be shot off to Ann Smith's mailbox and "conversion@work.com" mailbox.

Is it possible to make a policy in O365 that will check the shared mailbox delegates and reject the CC'ed person if it finds that person already in the shared mailbox?

Comment: It might be possible with Exchange transport rules. 
But I suggest you go via user education approach.
Or maybe offer them other communication tool for their needs, e.g. Teams

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you can assign a shared mailbox to a group (delegate access to group of users).

For the second part - it depends exactly, but I think you could either do it with simple exchange rule, or - if the problem is more complex - with MS Flow.